# Parsing firebase query data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase cloud firestore for storing data. And I am developing a web app using reactjs. I have obtained documents using the following function:

```
getPeoples() {
        let persons = [];
        firestore.collection("students")
            .get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    var person = {};
                    person.name = doc.data().Name;
                    person.course = doc.data().Course;
                    persons.push(person);
                })
            });
        console.log(persons);
        return persons;
    }
```

I am getting the desired data, but when I am iterating through **persons** array, it says it has length of 0.

here is the console output when I am displaying complete persons array and its length.

The length should be 14, but it shows 0. Please correct me what is wrong with me?

[image]

I want to display the output in the html inside the `render()` method of react component.

The output of

```
 const peoples = this.getPeoples();
        console.log(peoples);
```

It is: 
[image]

The complete render method looks like:

```
render() {
        const peoples = this.getPeoples();
        console.log(peoples);
        return (
            <div className="peopleContainer">
                <h2>Post-Graduate Students</h2>
                {/* <h4>{displayPerson}</h4> */}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact the query to the database is asynchronous and you are returning the `persons` array before this asynchronous task is finished (i.e. before the promise returned by the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method resolves).

You should return the `persons` array within the `then()`, as follows:

```
getPeoples() {
        let persons = [];
        return firestore.collection("students")
            .get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    var person = {};
                    person.name = doc.data().Name;
                    person.course = doc.data().Course;
                    persons.push(person);
                })
                console.log(persons);
                return persons;
            });
    }
```

And you need to call it as follows, because it will return a promise :

```
  getPeoples().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Have a look at what is written to the console if you do:

```
  console.log(getPeoples());

  getPeoples().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: But this returns persons array for every object. And also what if I use `getPeoples()` function to return the persons array? just like `const persons = getPeoples();`.

Comment: Can I create something like Person model class and create array of objects of the Person class in reactjs? If yes, Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but please try to update your

```
 getPeoples() {
    let persons = [];
    firestore.collection("students")
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                var person = {};
                person.name = doc.data().Name;
                person.course = doc.data().Course;
                persons.push(person);
            })
        });
    console.log(persons);
    return persons;
}
```

to

```
getPeoples() {
    let persons = [];
    firestore.collection("students")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                persons.push({name = doc.data().Name,
                course = doc.data().Course
            })
        });
    console.log(persons);
    return persons;
}
```

**Update**

Sorry I thought you have problem with filling persons array in your function. Anyway as Renaud mentioned the query in your function is asynchronous so the result is not quick enough to be displayed on render. I use similar function and I found redux the best way to handle this situations.